# JPA working with bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, jpa

I'm new to jpa, so please don't be strict with me. Maybe my question is stupid. But. I don't quite understand how to work with the bidirectional relationship. For example I have the following classes:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "book_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "book_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "book_id_seq_gen")
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int year;
    @ManyToOne
    private Writer writer;
    private String description;
    private int downloadNumber;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "book_genre",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
    )
    private Set<Genre> genres;
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Writer {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "writer_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "writer_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "writer_id_seq_gen")
    private long id;
    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    @Length(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Surname cannot be null")
    @Length(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String surname;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "writer")
    private List<Book> books;
}
```

I'm working with REST, so when I'm trying to return object back, I get a cycle. Okay, I fixed it with annotations for JSON. But. When I'm just trying to work with a collection of books in the writer I get the cycle. I can't work with the collection and I can't work with the writer either. So how to work with it at all?

Comment: What do you mean "I can't work with the collection"? What is stopping you from "working with the collection"?

Comment: Yes, I got it. I can work, but need to be careful. I got an error because I tried to use toString() :)